# How to use one output of a function and store a second one=

Tags: python, function

So I have a function which outputs 2 values:

```
def example(a, b):
    c = math.floor(a / b)
    a  = a%b
    return (c, a)
```

I want to use this function this way:

```
print("text: ", c)
```

How can I use the function and print c, but store x for later?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What is `x` (did you mean `a`)? Do you understand how to solve the problem when just returning a single value? **What exactly is the question here?** Please read [ask]. It's also not clear to me exactly what you think "store for later" entails. In the example code, I think `c` must have already been "stored for later".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function will return a tuple containing the two values.  You can assign the result of calling your function to a variable.

Note,

- that the parentheses are not required in your return statement.
- you can replace `math.floor(a / b)` with `a // b` which will also do a floor division.

An example is shown below where the result of calling the function is unpacked into two variables, `c` and `a`.

```
def example(a, b):
    c = a // b
    a  = a % b
    return c, a
    
c, a = example(6, 3)

print("text:", c)
```

Alternatively, you can also store the result in a single variable that references your tuple as follows:

```
data = example(6, 3)

print("text:", data[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to call the function and assign its return values to some variables:

```
x, y = example(42, 5)
```

Then you can print the results:

```
print(x)
print(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can even skip the variable assignment if you wish so

```
print("text:", example(a, b)[0])
```

but it's ugly